# How can I attach detail link to datagrid view column which I fill dynamically from a web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview

I fill data grid as follows: I took data from a webservice and fill gridview on the aspx file; I want to make ADVERTISEMENTNO column "a link" which shows details of Ad on the screen

```
public DataTable SgkTecrubeTabloOlustur(System.Collections.Generic.List<IstSgk4AHizmetBilgisiModel> listSgkTecrube)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ADVERTISEMENTNO", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("ADNAME", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("ADCODE", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("BEGINDATE", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("ENDDATE", typeof(string));


        for (int index = 0; index < listSgkTecrube.Count; index++)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            if (listSgkTecrube.ToArray()[index].ADVERTISEMENTNO!= null)
            {
                row[0] = listSgkTecrube.ToArray()[index].ADVERTISEMENTNO.ToString();
            }
            if (listSgkTecrube.ToArray()[index].ADNAME != null)
            {
                row[1] = listSgkTecrube.ToArray()[index].ADNAME.ToString();
            }
            if (listSgkTecrube.ToArray()[index].ADCODE!= null)
            {
                row[2] = listSgkTecrube.ToArray()[index].ADCODE.ToString();
            }
         
            if (listSgkTecrube.ToArray()[index].BEGINDATE!= null && !listSgkTecrube.ToArray()[index].BEGINDATE.ToString().Substring(0, 10).Equals("01.01.0001"))
            {
                row[5] = listSgkTecrube.ToArray()[index].BEGINDATE.ToString().Substring(0,10);
            }
            if (listSgkTecrube.ToArray()[index].ENDDATE != null && !listSgkTecrube.ToArray()[index].ENDDATE.ToString().Substring(0, 10).Equals("01.01.0001"))
            {
                row[6] = listSgkTecrube.ToArray()[index].ENDDATE.ToString().Substring(0, 10);
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

my aspx file is as follows:

```
      <iskurControls:IskurGridView runat="server"
                ID="ctlGridSgkTecrube"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                EmptyDataText="Tecrübe Bilginiz Bulunmamaktadır."
                EnableViewState="true"
                CssClass="table table-bordered table-condensed text-small">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ADVERTISEMENTNO" HeaderText="Ad No">
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ADNAME" HeaderText="AdName">
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
```

I can use

```
    <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left">

                        <%-- <HeaderTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="ctlIlanSayisi" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </HeaderTemplate>--%>

                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div style="padding-top: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px;">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="ctlPozisyonMeslekDL" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="False" Font-Bold="True"></asp:LinkButton>
                                &nbsp;
                                <asp:Image ID="ctlEngelGif" runat="server" Visible="false" ImageUrl='<%# GetImageUrlByStatus(Eval("PRMSOSYALDURUMKAYITNO").ToString()) %>' />
                            </div>
```

and my RowDataBound is as follows:

```
    protected void ctlGridAcikIslerListeDetail_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {  
        Control ctl = e.Row.FindControl("ctlPozisyonMeslekDL");
        if (ctl != null)
        {
            Literal literal = (Literal)ctl;

            object obj = DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(e.Row.DataItem, "ADVERTISEMENTNO");

            if (obj == null || Convert.IsDBNull(obj))
                literal.Text = "Detay";
            else if (SecurityContext.IsUser && SecurityContext.CurrentUser != null && SecurityContext.CurrentUser.IsInternalUser)
            {
                string userId = CurrentQueryHashedUserID;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
                    literal.Text = string.Format("<a href=\"javascript:PopupJobDetails('{0}',{1});\">{0}</a>", obj, IsAuthenticated ? 1 : 0);                    
            }
        }
```

but the problem is how can ı get ADVERTISMENTNO field as a value from  grid ?

Comment: DataItem ONLY exists during the data binding events of the GridView. Once databind of the grid is complete, then row.DataItem goes out of scope, and can't be used anymore. If you want to set the ImageURL of the LinkButton, then use the RowDataBound event of the GridView, and in that event, you can set the ImageURL, and during that event you have full use of row.dataitem.